# Error when uglifying webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, uglifyjs

We used to have a single bundle generated by Webpack in our application (we are using Angular 1.5~ to build the UI), however due to the single file being a bit bulky and many things were only required in specific areas of the application, I decided to separate my application in multiple bundles, i.e.:

```
app.bundle.js
trade.bundle.js
analysis.bundle.js
... and so on
```

On the development environment it worked flawlessly, however, when I tried to build it for production, which the only main difference is that we use the UglifyJS Plugin, to minify the bundles.

And now it doesn't work, the console displays an error "Could not set BrV of undefined", and then tons of other errors due to Angular being unable to load a module and nothing works.

BrV is a third-party plugin I am using for some input validations.

Having separated bundles minified seems to break some scripts which ends up breaking the whole application.

Here is my webpack conf (only the exports section)

```
// configuration.js
module.exports = {
    WEBCONTENT_FOLDER: '../WebContent/',
    PATH_TO_OUTPUT: '../WebContent/js/',
    ENTRIES: {
        app: '../WebContent/js/app.js',
        trade: '../WebContent/js/src/trade.js',
        reports: '../WebContent/js/src/reports.js',
        analysis: '../WebContent/js/src/analysis.js',
        wordpress: '../WebContent/js/src/wordpress.js'
    }
};

// common.js
module.exports = {
  entry: config.ENTRIES,

  module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: require.resolve(path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/forms')),
              use: 'exports-loader?addNavigation,ajaxCall,isChecked'
          }
      ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname)
    ],

    alias: {
      ThirdParty: path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/third-party'),
      App: path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/myApp'),
      JS: path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js'),
      JSP: path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'jsp')
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        addNavigation: [path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/forms'), 'addNavigation'],
        ajaxCall: [path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/forms'), 'ajaxCall']
    })
  ],

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(config.PATH_TO_OUTPUT, 'dist')
  },

  externals: {
      'angular': 'angular',
      'jquery': 'jQuery'
  }
};

// prod.js
module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
          rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.js$/,
                  use: [
                      { loader: 'ifdef-loader', options: opts}
                  ]
              }
          ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ngAnnotatePlugin({
            add: true,
        }),
        // I wasn't passing this object before, but I was trying to make it work, so I added this, mainly for the keep_fnames, which didn't do a thing though...
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            parallel: 4,
            sourceMap: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                ie8: false,
                mangle: {
                    keep_fnames: true
                }
            }
        }),
        new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
            files: {
                'vendor.js': [
                    path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/third-party/dropzone/dropzone.js'),
                    path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js/forms.js'),
                    path.resolve(config.WEBCONTENT_FOLDER, 'js//app/app.i18n.js'),
                ]
            },
            transform: {
                'vendor.js': code => require('uglify-js').minify(code).code
            }
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'ENV': 'prod'
        })
    ]
});
```

Does anyone have a clue on what might be happening? I can provide more info if needed. Thanks for the help.

Kind regards.

**EDIT - Solution**

*Turns out the error was due to faulty code on the BrV plugin indeed. I thought that it was just because it was the first library being loaded, and that even if I fixed this, I'd have trouble with lots of other plugins, but in the end, I fixed the code and everything worked. Thanks.*

Comment: "And now it doesn't work." Err, *what* doesn't work, exactly? Does UglifyJS throw an error? Do you get a JavaScript error when loading the file in a browser?

Comment: Sorry, I got side tracked while writing the question that I forgot about that. Will edit my question to include this. I am getting this error "Could not set BrV of undefined", when my pages are loading. BrV being a third-party validation plugin I am using.

Comment: This is just a guess but I know Angular 1's dependency injection method can have some issues when uglified/minified so that might be something to look into.

Comment: It did have some issues, but once I included the annotate plugin it worked. It was working fine before I split the app in multiple bundles.